# PySpark - Restart logic based on elapsed time

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have quite a difficult exercise at hands and I am starting to believe it is not possible to solve it in Spark.

Imagine the following dataframe:

| date | timestamp | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-06 | 2022-05-06 08:00:00 | -0.2 |
| 2022-05-05 | 2022-05-05 06:00:00 | -0.15 |
| 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-10 10:00:00 | -0.2 |
| 2022-03-05 | 2022-03-05 08:00:00 | -0.3 |
| 2022-03-04 | 2022-03-04 04:00:00 | -0.1 |
| 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-05 06:00:00 | -0.3 |
| 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-04 04:00:00 | -0.6 |
| 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-03 15:00:00 | -0.1 |
| 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-03 10:00:00 | -0.15 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 14:00:00 | -0.3 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 12:00:00 | -0.1 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | -0.2 |

What I want to achieve is the following:

- If the value decreases by more than 0.1 from the minimum observed until that row raise a flag.
- If more than 30days elapsed apply the logic above but from the row nearest to where the 30days elapsed.

| date | timestamp | value | min_value_until_now | date_from_min | flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-06 | 2022-05-06 08:00:00 | -0.2 | -0.15 | 2022-05-05 | 0 |
| 2022-05-05 | 2022-05-05 06:00:00 | -0.15 | -0.15 | 2022-05-05 | 1 -->Note3 |
| 2022-03-10 | 2022-03-10 10:00:00 | -0.2 | -0.3 | 2022-03-05 | 0 |
| 2022-03-05 | 2022-03-05 08:00:00 | -0.3 | -0.1 | 2022-03-04 | 1 |
| 2022-03-04 | 2022-03-04 04:00:00 | -0.1 | -0.1 | 2022-03-04 | 1 -->Note2 |
| 2022-01-05 | 2022-01-05 06:00:00 | -0.3 | -0.6 | 2022-01-04 | 0 |
| 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-04 04:00:00 | -0.6 | -0.3 | 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-03 15:00:00 | -0.1 | -0.3 | 2022-01-02 | 0 |
| 2022-01-03 | 2022-01-03 10:00:00 | -0.15 | -0.3 | 2022-01-02 | 0 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 14:00:00 | -0.3 | -0.2 | 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-02 12:00:00 | -0.1 | -0.2 | 2022-01-01 | 0 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 12:00:00 | -0.2 | -0.2 | 2022-01-01 | 1 -->Note1* |

Note1: When there is no historical data, then pick the first value.

Note2: When more than 30days have elapsed since the last flag, then forget the past and pick the first value. i.e. the row (or data point ) closest to the 30days.

The code belows allows me to pick the latest minimum value on record. However, the values decrease monotonically. Thus, flags will only be raised if some extreme event happens. What I would like is to apply a "reset" based on an elapsed time condition to the logic below.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.orderBy("timestamp").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, -1)

df.withColumn(
    "min_value_until_now",
    F.coalesce(F.min("value").over(w), F.col("value"))
).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rangeBetween` instead of `rowsBetween`.

```
# need long type to use `rangeBetween` with dates
df = df.withColumn('long_timestamp', df.timestamp.cast(TimestampType()).cast(LongType()))

# Look up to 30 days before
w = Window.orderBy('long_timestamp').rangeBetween(-30*24*60*60, -1)

df.withColumn(
    "min_value_until_now",
    F.coalesce(F.min("value").over(w), F.col("value"))
).show()
```

Comment: Not sure the text is clear, but this solution does not reset the value after 30days. 

If we had 2 rows before 2022-03-04:
.... 
 2022-03-04  | 2022-03-04 04:00:00  |  -0.1
*2022-03-01  | 2022-03-01 00:00:00  |  -0.1
*2022-02-03  | 2022-02-03 00:00:00  |  -0.15
 2022-01-05  | 2022-01-05 06:00:00  |  -0.3
...

Then the flag would not be triggered

Comment: I'm getting confused.  Is your 2nd table's `min_value_until_now` is expected output? I am not yet calculating the `flag`.